# Physical button/momentary switch to trigger a keyboard shortcut in Excel on Windows

Tags: usb, bluetooth, remote-control

I work in a manufacturing environment and we use vba macros in excel spreadsheets on a laptop to log completion times when we finish up a process.

I'm looking for a physical button that can be pressed to trigger the macro instead, that way we can have the laptop somewhere else and also should be easier to press a button rather than a keyboard shortcut (among other things).

Here's what I'm looking for in my button:

- Momentary and not toggle---One of the buttons I tried out clicked in, but then had to be unclicked.
- Bluetooth would be preferred over a USB connection, but not required.
- Needs to trigger a customizable keyboard shortcut (ctrl+a, ctrl+shift+k, etc) to run a macro inside of excel

I tried a device from espruino called [*puck.js v2.*](https://www.puck-js.com/) It's a bluetooth button that runs javascript, but it runs off of javascript and I don't know how I could make that run a keyboard shortcut for the macro.

Comment: You can get a normal keyboard that supports a lot of macro's like the Sharkoon SGK5, although you will have to memorize which macro is which button. And I don't know if it supports Excel nativly since I don't use Excel

Comment: you can trigger a keyboard shortcut though like ctrl+s with one key, that exists

Answer (score 1):

On Mac it's called "Switch Control" idk what Windows calls it. It's an accessibility feature for physically impaired users, using different types of switch depending on their incapacity. You can define in the OS how you use these to interact with features, from simple triggers to entire keyboard input. You could take a simple switch input & using such as [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) define it as your macro trigger.

Famously, Steven Hawking used such a device to communicate with the world.

One of the foremost manufacturers is [Axess Lab](https://axesslab.com/switches/)

[Riverside](https://www.riverside.org.uk/accessibility/accessibility-tools-on-your-computer-or-device/) has a simple overview of accessibility controls for Win & Mac, though the Win section seems a bit light [idk how Windows handles such as this, sorry]